# How do I rotate a shape around a certain center, in increments smaller than 1 degree?

Tags: sketch-app

Using the Rotate tool, every rotation is in increments of 1 degree, but I want to rotate something 7.5 degrees. I can do this using Transform in the right pane, but then I can't pick a custom center point to rotate around.

Is there a way to get the best of both worlds, by rotating around a custom center point in increments smaller than 1 degree?

Answer (score 2):

You can rotate by 0.1 degree by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and increasing or decreasing value in Transform field by <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> keys.  Additionally, you can enter values directly into the Transform area's rotate box— it supports increments smaller than 0.1°.

To rotate around a custom center, select the rotate tool and drag the centerpoint wherever you please.

[image]

Comment: When I use the arrow keys, the shape (including the custom center) always rotates around its (non-custom) center, whether I hold alt or not.